# Want to create a custom order by using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-order-by

I need to create a custom order by using mysqli
conside i have a table like below

```
id         name

1          Della
2          Cory
3          Adams
4          Paul
5          Martin
6          Gilbert
```

from the above table i need to fetch Cory first and then Della,Adams,Paul,Martin and finally Gilbert 
how can i do that?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: i think i just need the mysql orderby syntax for above table

Comment: if you already know, then what is your question ?

Comment: why cory first? any reason? Seems like rest will come with `ASC` order apart from `cory`

Comment: Please kindly read my question again

Comment: @AlivetoDie its just the random data. Really i need to create a custom order by

Comment: what do you mean by custom order, custom is very broad term. You aren't showing what have you tried so far neither telling the logic

Comment: You can try this SELECT * FROM people 
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'Cory', 'Della','Adams','Paul','Martin','Gilbert');